# Format for GradientStopCollection.Parse()?

Tags: .net, wpf

`GradientStopCollection` have very useful method to create it from saved string. But it's nowhere documented what it expect for input. MSDN is [unbelievable laconic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.gradientstopcollection.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) about that.
First intuitive idea is to use what its opposite `ToString()` method returns. It gives a simple format, an example - `#FFFFFFFF;1 #FF0000FF;0,25 #FFFF0000;0,5 #FFFFFF00;0,75 #FF000000;0`. But if you try to parse that string, there will be a totally uninformant error "Token is not valid.".

Trying to google it I realized noone except me is using that method. Weird.
I found [source code of that method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationCore/a.html#28edfbd62bc370d1), but it's too "internal" for me to understand.

Of course I can parse that string manually with like one LINQ query, but it's like matter of principle for me now, to understand how it is supposed to work :) Also, less code is better and I don't like to reinvent another bikes.

So, anyone ever used that method or may be can understand from sources what format it expects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the source code you mentioned and [TokenizerHelper Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Shared/MS/Internal/TokenizerHelper.cs), I can say:

1. Use the same separator `,` between colour and doubles and between pairs
2. Use `.` as the integer/fraction seperator in your doubles
3. For colour you can use any string parsable as colour even something like `White`, and also the hex code which you've used

Considering all this we come to `#FFFFFFFF,1,#FF0000FF,0.25,#FFFF0000,0.5,#FFFFFF00,0.75,#FF000000,0` which runs without throwing an exception

Comment: It's working, thank you. Isn't it weird that format of output and input is different without any explanations?

Btw, did you notice any culture dependencies there? Because I remember once my app that was working perfectly, parsing  any inputed decimal separators became broken in other country due to different decimal separator character in system settings.

Comment: @WolfrevoCats Because of `IFormatProvider formatProvider = System.Windows.Markup.TypeConverterHelper.InvariantEnglishUS` I don't think its culture dependent.

Comment: That's unbelievable (again!), it turns out, that even when `Parse()` method is not culture-dependent, the opposite one `ToString()` is! I just caught a bug in my app on a PC with current culture set to US and string representation of my gradient in example above becomes:
`#FFFFFFFF,1 #FF0000FF,0.25 #FFFF0000,0.5 #FFFFFF00,0.75 #FF000000,0` ! Which can be parsed.


Considering this, I clearly see a bug in realization of couple of those  methods. First one using current culture, and second one fixed to EnglishUS. I think I'll post a bug to .NET community since they are open-sourced now.

Comment: Here is bug submitted - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3132304